# R Studio keyboard shortcut for source pane - jump between tabs and spreadsheet data

Tags: r, rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts

I can <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to jump to my console and then type `View(mtcars)` to get a spreadsheet in my source pane.

I then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to get back to my source pane. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> then moves around the tabs in my source pane. But how do I *jump* down to the data in the spreadsheet. I can *click* with my mouse in the spreadsheet and then browse around with my keyboard arrows. But I don't like using the mouse.

I'm hoping there's a keyboard trick I can do to jump from the source pane tab, down to the spreadsheet data, without having to take my hands off the keyboard to do this manually via mouse. I do it so often. And conversely, once I'm in the spreadsheet data, how do I jump back up to the source pane tabs without having to use the mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think this is currently possible -- I've filed a feature request on your behalf on the [RStudio issue tracker](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2451).